# Como editar o nome das variáveis em um ggplot sem ter que alterar os dados da tabela?

Tags: r

Eu plotei meu gráfico mas gostaria de mudar o nome das minha variáveis do eixo x e y (não o nome do eixo) para melhor visualização das informações sem ter que mudar tudo na planilha matriz. É possível fazer essa alteração pelo script?
Por exemplo, eu gostaria de mudar o nome de uma das variáveis y chamada Fran para #MB02 as variáveis do eixo x 134321 por #R01. Conseguiria usando == por exemplo?

Segue abaixo exemplo da matriz base usada para criar os objetos necessários.

```
myc_t
Date    Time    Receiver    Transmitter ID  Transmitter.Serial  Sensor.Value Sensor.Unit    Station Name    Longitude   Latitude
2019-04-29  05:31:33    134321  4828    Fran    1305297         28.7       °C             PRN               102          121
2019-04-29  08:52:08    134325  4830    Beni    1305283         4.2         m             MVW               102          178
2019-04-29  08:53:13    134325  4831    Silvo   1305283         28.6       °C             MVW               150          178



plot(rec_loc$Longitude,rec_loc$Latitude,pch=1,cex=1,col="black",xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude")
as.factor(myc_t$Receiver)->myc_t$Receiver
as.factor(myc_t$Transmitter)->myc_t$Transmitter
levels(myc_t$Transmitter)->tlev
levels(myc_t$Receiver)->rlev
dput(myc_t)
ggplot(myc_t, aes(x=Receiver, y=Transmitter))+ geom_point() + xlab("ID dos receptores") + ylab("ID dos tags") +
scale_x_discrete(labels = rlev) + scale_y_discrete(labels = tlev)
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(myc_t)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(myc_t, 20))`?

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que seja isso que procura:

```
    ggplot(myc_t, aes(x=Receiver, y=Transmitter))+ geom_point() + xlab("ID dos receptores") + ylab("ID dos tags") +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("#R01", "#R02")) + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("#MB01", "#MB02", "#MB03"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Isso! Muito obrigada! Mas como eu faço para colocar as variáveis na horizontal? Obrigada!

Comment: Gente, não consigo colocar as variáveis do eixo X na horizontal mesmo usando las=1. alguém pode ajudar???

Comment: Veja se é isso que precisa! Modifiquei minha resposta!